# Print all alphabetic characters between two indices

Tags: c

I'm having a bit of trouble with this question.  I keep getting a "build succeeded" (I'm working in xCode) but no printed output.

Here is the question:

"Write a program and a void function.  The void function will take two ints as pass-by-value parameters.  These two ints give the start and the end (the start guaranteed to be smaller than the end) of the range of positions within the alphabet sequence (A is zero, B is one, etc.)  The function must then print the start capital letter and subsequently every capital letter in the ascending FOR loop.  You may use put char() or printf.  Example:  If the user types "CJ", the ints passed to the function would be 2 and 9, and the printed output would be "CDEFGHIJ".

And here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void writeLetters (int begin, int end);

int main() {

    char beginChar, endChar;
    int beginInt, endInt;

    scanf("%c%c", beginChar, endChar);

    beginInt = beginChar*1;
    endInt = endChar*1;

    writeLetters(beginInt, endInt);

    return 0;
}

void writeLetters (int begin, int end) {

    int i;
    char beginChar = begin*'A', endChar = end*'A';

    for (i=begin; i<=end; i++) {

        printf("%c", beginChar);
        beginChar += 'A';
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you actually run the code, vs. just compiling it?

Comment: If begin > end it won't print anything. What input are you giving the program?

Comment: I think you're mistaking the `*` operator for the `-` operator.

Comment: You are missing the & in scan statement. scanf("%c%c", &beginChar, &endChar);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a number of issues; some have already been pointed out, others haven't. Look at your `writeLetters` function, which increments `beginChar` by `'A'` every time through the loop.

Try this:

```
void writeLetters (int begin, int end) 
{
    while(begin <= end)
    {
        printf("%c", 'A' + begin);
        begin++;
    }
}

int main() 
{
    char beginChar, endChar;

    scanf("%c%c", &beginChar, &endChar);

    /* live dangerously - don't error check scanf and don't
     * sanitize the input. In real life, you should always
     * practice safe hex.
     */
    writeLetters(beginChar - 'A', endChar - 'A');

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%d%d", &beginInt, &endInt);    
....

void writeLetters (int begin, int end)
{
   int i;

   for (i=begin; i <= end; i++)
   {
       printf("%c", (char)('A' + i));
   }
}
```